# Python Django: basic GET/POST function

Tags: django

I tried 2 things. In the first case, when the user clicks on the submit button, the application should just say "hello world".

this is the html file:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="/try/" name="clickme" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="click me" /> <br>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Views.py file:

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

    def index(request):

        return render_to_response('firstpypypro/index.html')
        if request.method == 'GET':
            print("just checking") # this was just for me to check
            return HttpResponse('hello')

    def what(request):
        return HttpResponse("whooooo")
```

And this is the urls.py file:

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
    from firstpypypro.views import index,what

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', index),
        url(r'^try/$', what),
    )
```

When I run the django web server, it gives error that it couldn't find any url matching to 127.0.0.1/8000/try. What went wrong here?

And also I am really struggling to understand a simple thing which is to accept values from html form to back end script and how to give values from the back end to html. Can you please explain even in short or give me some simple links to understand?

Like suppose in this html file, if there was a text box also, and if i enter my name and click submit, it will display my name. How to do this basic thing?

Comment: Url should be `127.0.0.1:8000/try` instead of `127.0.0.1/8000/try`.

Comment: @Neha Verma try in urls.py  url(r'^try/', what),

Comment: @AvinashGarg There is nothing wrong with `$`... It marks the end of a line.

Comment: These are two different problems. Try fix the url problem first and then tackle the POST/GET issue

Comment: Sorry mate, I have posted my answer, I have also checked it in my own application and it works just fine, I think that you doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

and for getting value in backend you can use

html

```
<form method="post" action='...'>
<input type="email" name="email_id"
    placeholder="Your e-mail"><br/>
</form>


def demo_method(request):
      email_id=request.POST.get('email_id'))
```

Comment: hi avinash i tried that url but again it didn't work :(

Comment: @NehaVerma check you url it is 127.0.0.1:8000/try right??

Comment: server shows it as 127.0.0.1:8000/try/? when i click on the submit button

Comment: @NehaVerma ahhh.. use it <form action="/try" method="GET"> in forms  and in urls url(r'^try/', what) now check,,,,,

Comment: didnt work :/ now it shows url on browser as 127.0.0.1/8000/try?

Comment: @NehaVerma okay last try ...in urlpatterns = patterns('projectname',
        url(r'^$', index),
        url(r'^try/$', what),
    )    
jst enter your project name in urlpatterns as shown above